# How to avoid duplicate optional arguments in overloads?

Tags: c#, overloading, optional-parameters

In C#, I have a function of the form

```
void Foo(Vector<double> v, int k = 1)
{ ... }
```

where `Vector<double>` is a type from the `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra` package which represents a mathematical column vector. Semantically, it would make a lot of sense to be able to call this method with a double in place of the vector, so that the caller does not have to cast a scalar to a 1D vector in the 1D case. Hence I have also made an overload of the following form:

```
void Foo(double d, int k = 1) => Foo(d.ToVector(), k);
```

(`ToVector` is an extension method.) The problem with this is that the default value `k = 1` must be added in both signatures. Thus, if I ever want to change the default value, I must remember to do it in two places. A possible solution could be to replace the overload with the following two:

```
void Foo(double d) => Foo(d.ToVector());
void Foo(double d, int k) => Foo(d.ToVector(), k);
```

But what if I had not one, but N optional arguments? With this solution I would then need 2^N overloads.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can't you use a constant?

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea! I suppose you mean like `const int defaultK = 1;` and then `void Foo(Vector<double> v, int k = defaultK)`, and similar in the overload?

Comment: @shingo Feel free to write your comment as an answer if you want the credit, and I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a constant as the default value, this way, you only need to maintain this constant.

```
public const int DefaultK = 1;

void Foo(Vector<double> v, int k = DefaultK)
{ ... }

void Foo(double d, int k = DefaultK)
{ ... }
```